# Why are there 8 Deductions, and not 6, in Plato's Parmenides?

Tags: metaphysics, plato, platonism

In Plato's Parmenides, we have the 8 Deductions that go something like this (this applies, as best as I can see, to both the standard and non-standard models that the SEoP describes. All this is shamelessly lifted from the SEoP site):

> 1. If the G is, then the G is not F and not con-F in relation to itself.
> 2. If the G is, then the G is F and con-F in relation to the others.
> 3. If the G is, then the others are F and con-F in relation to the G.
> 4. If the G is, then the others are not F and not con-F in relation to themselves.
> 5. If the G is not, then the G is F and con-F in relation to the others.
> 6. If the G is not, then the G is not F and not con-F in relation to itself.
> 7. If the G is not, then the others are F and con-F in relation to the G.
> 8. If the G is not, then the others are not F and not con-F in relation to themselves.
>
> - https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plato-parmenides/

I decided to plot these out on a truth table.

[image: "Is it F & Con-F?"]

What interests me here is the latter two columns; "Others to G" and "Others to Themselves".
Looking at these, we can see that **Deductions 3 and 7**, along with **Deductions 4 and 8**, actually have the *exact same results and implications* **(EDIT) and do not care about the state of G.**

My question is; does this not mean that we can simplify the Deductions down to a total of 6, like this?:

1. If the G is, then the G is not F and not con-F in relation to itself.
2. If the G is, then the G is F and con-F in relation to the others.
3. If the G is not, then the G is F and con-F in relation to the others.
4. If the G is not, then the G is not F and not con-F in relation to itself.
5. **The others are F and con-F in relation to the G.**
6. **The others are not F and not con-F in relation to themselves.**

There's likely something super obvious I don't get, I'm not a trained or educated philosopher. I just came across this and found it interesting, was wondering if someone with a bigger thinking sponge than mine could explain!